# Web admin interface accounts and password boxes disappeared

Tags: geoserver

I just updated GeoServer from 2.15 to 2.21. I downloaded geoserver.war and substituted it for the previous one then put the old data folder back.
At first I was able to connect to the web admin interface except that my admin password has been changed, and there I no longer have the accounts and password boxes. They have disappeared from the login page. So I can no longer log in. What to do?

and geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.GeoServerLoginPage?7

[image]

[log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1He1jI2XbOja9wz77pfnuXVVFeYDmv-lM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If your password changed then your data directory wasn't found, You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: How  can I acces to the global settings page ?

Comment: ok i did it but the log is too long
how can i put a file ?

Comment: ok i put a link to the file

Comment: we need just the **relevant** part of your log file - just the part showing the error

Comment: i don't know what you are looking for in this file

Comment: I put the file above

Comment: that looks like a normal start up with no data directory defined. Which user did you log in as?

Comment: i was log as admin but now I can't log because there's no where to log because user and password are not visible and that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Restarting the geoserver with `service geoserver restart` solved it.